# How to fix workers.api.error.script_too_large when deploying Sveltekit to Cloudflare pages

Tags: svelte, cloudflare, sveltekit, cloudflare-pages

I've been working on a sveltekit blog using mdsvex. The .md files have svelte components. I now have more than 200 posts with multiple components each.

Everything was working well, but recently started getting the following error when deploying to Cloudflare pages:

*Your Functions script is over the 1 MiB size limit (workers.api.error.script_too_large)
*

I suspect the problem is that the _worker.js inside the cloudflare folder contains all the blog posts info, and it is getting large (although don't know exactly what it does).

I'm using prerender = true, but also tried different options like prerender = false, csr = false, and still getting the same error.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Should I use something different than mdsvex?

I also tried using the following configs for the adapter

```
adapter({routes: {
include: ['/*'],
exclude: ['/january/*', '/february/*', '/countdowns/*', '/days/*', '/_worker.js' ]
}
})
```

Comment: My first suggestion would be use Node.js adapter for hosting instead of Cloudflare workers, but this might not be the thing you want to hear. Node adapter has much more flexibility than any serverless or worker based system and not subject to similar restrictions.